# Rails 3.2: Select option not remembered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having a strange issue where my select options are not remembered on submit (and validations fail, re-loading the form).

Here is my code

`<%= form.select :state, options_for_select(us_states), :include_blank => true %>`

Here is some of what us_states looks like:

```
  def us_states
      [
        ['Alabama', 'AL'],
        ['Alaska', 'AK'],
```

No matter what I select, it always picks to display the blank option in the select box. If I don't use the :include_blank at all, it always just displays Alabama. So it's just displaying the first field.

Comment: When you remove `:include_blank => true` then it works correctly? Without touching any other code?

Comment: Oops, nope, it just displays Alabama always then. Updated the question.

Comment: Please mark one of the questions as correct. The top answer worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the selected value by passing it as an argument to the `options_for_select` helper.

```
<%= form.select :state, options_for_select(us_states, form.object.state), :include_blank => true %>
```

---

Documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out all I had to do was pass in the second argument to options_for_select. So I got this working by

`options_for_select(us_states, @user.state)`

Comment: I would give this +10 if I could.

Comment: While this is correct, I accepted Wizard of Ogz's answer which is the same. Would rather accept someone else's answer than my own.

Answer (score 0):

### Ok, Its my turn.

*I will tell you how I use it in my application,
with example*

**The code below forms the select box.**

```
<%= select("product", "id",options_for_select(MobilesLists.get_colors(mobile.mobile_name))) %>
```

**The result of MobilesLists.get_colors is as follows,**

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :011 > MobilesLists.get_colors("Samsung Galaxy Y S5360")

=> [["black", 3], ["bubblegum pink", 5], ["fruity orange", 4], ["metallic grey", 1], ["silver platter", 6], ["white", 2]]
```

**It returns an array of arrays. So, now it becomes,**

```
 <%= select("product", "id",options_for_select([["black", 3], ["bubblegum pink", 5], ["fruity orange", 4], ["metallic grey", 1], ["silver platter", 6], ["white", 2]])) %>
```

**The above example generates the following HTML,**

```
<select id="product_id" name="product[id]"><option value="3">black</option>
<option value="5">bubblegum pink</option>
<option value="4">fruity orange</option>

<option value="1">metallic grey</option>
<option value="6">silver platter</option>
<option value="2">white</option></select>
```

**Now, in my controller I will access the value as follows,**

```
if !params[:product][:id].nil?

  @product_id = params[:product][:id].to_i

end
```

### Thats it!, Thanks!

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I was asking how to get the select box to default to the selected value when the form reloaded.